# how to get top 5 results from database along with all matched results

Tags: php, mysql

I want to show top 3 results and if is there are any results which match with top 3, they should also be fetched. In the examples below there are top 3 results, 50,40 and 30, but ram also has a mark of 30, so I want to fetch that result as well.

my database sheet table

| id | user | marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ram | 30 |
| 3 | sam | 30 |
| 4 | ben | 40 |
| 2 | hari | 10 |
| 5 | joe | 50 |

i want to return  top 3 results along with all matching results which is match to last result

| id | user | marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | joe | 50 |
| 4 | ben | 40 |
| 3 | sam | 30 |
| 1 | ram | 30 |

```
$top_results = "SELECT * FROM `sheet` ORDER BY `marks` DESC LIMIT 3"
```

and it only return top 3 not the 4 results

i want to show top 3 results and if is there any results match with top 3 also fetched, in above case there is top 3 results are 50,40 and 30 but ram has also 30. So I want to fetch that result also if it is their along with top 3

Comment: You have mentioned `top 3` and `top 4` and `top 5` Do you know what you want or not?

Comment: `LIMIT X` clause only buffers `X`(if available) records into the result-set. If you want all, the remove `LIMIT` clause; top `3` records will be there along with others. You can't have your cake & eat it.

Comment: Also Please do not SPAM Tags, they are there to gather the correct audience for your quesiton.

Comment: Your question makes very little sence, you already have a `LIMIT 3` so if you want top 4 then change it to `LIMIT 4` etc

Comment: i want to show top 3 results and if is there any results match with top 3 also fetched, in above case there is top 3 results are 50,40 and 30 but ram has also 30 so i want to fetch that result aslo if it is their along with top 3 @RiggsFolly

Comment: that would have been useful in the question, it still would be useful in the question. Please edit that into your question

Answer (score 0):

> I want to show top 3 results and if is there are any results which match with top 3, they should also be fetched.

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM table t1
JOIN ( SELECT result
       FROM table t2
       ORDER BY result DESC LIMIT 2,1 ) t3 ON t1.result >= t2.result
```

> how to get top 5 results from database along with all matched results

Adjust LIMIT accordingly - `LIMIT 4,1`.